# Looking for a book of short stories - man can understand animals talking

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

Back in the 80's I had a book of short stories that I loved, but now I can't remember the title.  I got the book when I lived in England, so it's possibly a British publication.

One of the stories was about a man who suffered some sort of head trauma (maybe had a metal plate put in his head), and he could understand animals talking, namely some ducks/swans that lived near his home.  I think the cover of the version I owned had a pencil drawing of a duck or possibly cat on the front and the title might have had the word quiet or silence in it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: This was different from Doctor Doolittle I take it

Comment: Yeah, not Dr. Doolittle.  This was only one of the short stories in the book, but it was the title story.